# Is it acceptable / correct to use integers as class names in this case

Tags: html, css, grid, semantics

I'm creating a simple to use responsive grid and at the moment have following code

```
.column {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}

.column.12 {
    width: 100%;
}

/* .. */

.column.6 {
    width: 50%;
}

/* .. */
```

Where integer relates to different size of a column

```
<div class="column 12"></div>
```

Above is an example usage.

Comment: Note that googling *"can class names start with a digit"* brings other QA, choose the one you like most for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Class names cannot [start or be digits](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner). An alternative would be to make class names that *end* with digits to signify their meaning.

```
.column12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.column6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `[class*="12"]` works fine as a selector.

Comment: `[att*=value]` translates to "The attribute’s value contains the specified value". It is still not valid to start with, or be, a number

Comment: @DavidRandall `*=` was simply an example. It's still possible to only select on a number though, regardless, it's just a bit long-winded: http://jsfiddle.net/rLxxE/1. :) (I'm not saying this is at all logical or good practice, however).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I agree it is possible, just not recommended :)